# C# Saving only Print Area of Excel Sheet as HTML

Tags: html, excel

I am trying to export part of an excel sheet as HTML. I can export the entire sheet, but not just the print area. How do you set the area to be saved as HTML?
This did not work. Saved the whole sheet, not just the print area:

```
oSheet = newBook.Worksheets[1];
oSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$F$19";
XlFileFormat xfm = XlFileFormat.xlHtml;
newBook.SaveAs(htmlFn, xfm,null,null,null,true,XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
```